# 'load.tds' DOM event type and jQuery .bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been reviewing for a friend a buggy and unmaintained Wordpress theme called [Touchfolio](http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/demo/) and I found this at line 2057 of the script [jquery.slider-pack.js](http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/demo/wp-content/themes/touchfolio/js/jquery.slider-pack.js)

```
.bind('load.tds', self._onLoadingComplete({
    type: 'loaded', 
    loadDataItem: currQueueItem, 
    block: currBlock, 
    img: currImg 
}))
```

The bind method is called as the callback and the event is triggered even if I couldn't find any reference to that DOM event type on MDN, jQuery or in this code ! (I also tried main.js and the other scripts available)

Could someone explain this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event being used is the normal `load` event. The `X.Y` syntax means that the event handler namespaced, in this case by `tds`. It can be used to identify and separate events belonging to a single plugin.

More information in the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

Also note that `bind()` is considered an outdated method. If possible you should consider upgrading the version of jQuery you're using, and changing to the `on()` method instead.